# carousel with popup when clicking on the image error

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, carousel

I am trying to create a image carousel and when clicking on one of the images, the exact image enlarges in a popup with a close button. Right now, i'm having this issue where when i click on the second image on the carousel, the popup comes up with the first picture on the carousel.

Here is my HTML Code

```
<div class="carousel">

            <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-1" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="" checked="checked">
            <div class="carousel-item">

                <img src="C:\Users\uppil\OneDrive\Desktop\WD\SS project\Used Resources\Wildlife 1.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" width="351" height="256" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    
            </div>
            <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-2" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
            <div class="carousel-item">
                
                <img src="C:\Users\uppil\OneDrive\Desktop\WD\SS project\Used Resources\Wildlife 2.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" width="351" height="256"  class="hover-shadow cursor">
            </div>
 
            <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-3" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
            <div class="carousel-item">
                
                <img src="C:\Users\uppil\OneDrive\Desktop\WD\SS project\Used Resources\Wildlife 3.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" width="351" height="256"  class="hover-shadow cursor">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                
                <img src="C:\Users\uppil\OneDrive\Desktop\WD\SS project\Used Resources\Wildlife 4.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" width="351" height="256"  class="hover-shadow cursor">
            </div>

    
            <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-control prev control-1">‹</label>
            <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-control next control-1">›</label>
            <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-control prev control-2">‹</label>
            <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-control next control-2">›</label>
            <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-control prev control-3">‹</label>
            <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-control next control-3">›</label>
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li>
                    <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
                </li>
              
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
        <div class="modal-content">
           
          <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
            <img src="C:\Users\uppil\OneDrive\Desktop\WD\SS project\Used Resources\Wildlife 1.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
          </div>
      
      

          <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
            <img src="C:\Users\uppil\OneDrive\Desktop\WD\SS project\Used Resources\Wildlife 2.jpg" style="width:100%">
          </div>

          <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
            <img src="C:\Users\uppil\OneDrive\Desktop\WD\SS project\Used Resources\Wildlife 3.jpg" style="width:100%">
          </div>

           <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
            <img src="C:\Users\uppil\OneDrive\Desktop\WD\SS project\Used Resources\Wildlife 3.jpg" style="width:100%">
          </div>
          <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
            <img src="C:\Users\uppil\OneDrive\Desktop\WD\SS project\Used Resources\Wildlife 4.jpg" style="width:100%">
          </div>

        
          
          <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
          <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      
          <div class="caption-container">
            <p id="caption"></p>
          </div>
```

Here is my JavaScript Code

```
 function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}



$(document).ready(function() {

var sync1 = $("#sync1");
var sync2 = $("#sync2");
var slidesPerPage = 4; //globaly define number of elements per page
var syncedSecondary = true;

sync1.owlCarousel({
  items : 1,
  slideSpeed : 2000,
  nav: true,
  //autoplay: true,
  dots: true,
  loop: true,
  responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
  navText: ['<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 11 20"><path style="fill:none;stroke-width: 1px;stroke: #FFF;" d="M9.554,1.001l-8.607,8.607l8.607,8.606"/></svg>','<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 11 20" version="1.1"><path style="fill:none;stroke-width: 1px;stroke: #FFF;" d="M1.054,18.214l8.606,-8.606l-8.606,-8.607"/></svg>'],
}).on('changed.owl.carousel', syncPosition);

sync2
  .on('initialized.owl.carousel', function () {
    sync2.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("current");
  })
  .owlCarousel({
  items : slidesPerPage,
  dots: true,
  nav: true,
  smartSpeed: 200,
  slideSpeed : 500,
  slideBy: slidesPerPage, //alternatively you can slide by 1, this way the active slide will stick to the first item in the second carousel
  responsiveRefreshRate : 100
}).on('changed.owl.carousel', syncPosition2);

function syncPosition(el) {
  //if you set loop to false, you have to restore this next line
  //var current = el.item.index;
  
  //if you disable loop you have to comment this block
  var count = el.item.count-1;
  var current = Math.round(el.item.index - (el.item.count/2) - .5);
  
  if(current < 0) {
    current = count;
  }
  if(current > count) {
    current = 0;
  }
  
  //end block

  sync2
    .find(".owl-item")
    .removeClass("current")
    .eq(current)
    .addClass("current");
  var onscreen = sync2.find('.owl-item.active').length - 1;
  var start = sync2.find('.owl-item.active').first().index();
  var end = sync2.find('.owl-item.active').last().index();
  
  if (current > end) {
    sync2.data('owl.carousel').to(current, 100, true);
  }
  if (current < start) {
    sync2.data('owl.carousel').to(current - onscreen, 100, true);
  }
}

function syncPosition2(el) {
  if(syncedSecondary) {
    var number = el.item.index;
    sync1.data('owl.carousel').to(number, 100, true);
  }
}

sync2.on("click", ".owl-item", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var number = $(this).index();
  sync1.data('owl.carousel').to(number, 300, true);
});
});







$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      closeOnContentClick: true,
      mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
      image: {
          verticalFit: true
      }
      
  });

  $('.image-popup-fit-width').magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      closeOnContentClick: true,
      image: {
          verticalFit: false
      }
  });

  $('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      closeOnContentClick: true,
      closeBtnInside: false,
      fixedContentPos: true,
      mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
      image: {
          verticalFit: true
      },
      zoom: {
          enabled: true,
          duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
      }
  });

});
```

Here is my CSS

```
html, body {
                        margin: 0px;
                        padding: 0px;
                        
                        background-color: black;
                }

            .carousel {
                        position: relative;
                        box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64);
                        margin-top: 26px;
                    }

            .carousel-inner {
                        position: relative;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        width: 100%;
                    }

            .carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
                        position: static;
                        opacity: 100;
                    }

            .carousel-item {
                position: absolute;
                opacity: 0;
                -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
                transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
    
                margin-left: 800px;
            }

            .carousel-item img {
                display: block;
                height: auto;
                max-width: 100%;
            }

            .carousel-control {
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
                border-radius: 50%;
                color: #fff;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: none;
                font-size: 40px;
                height: 40px;
                line-height: 35px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
                cursor: pointer;
                -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
                transform: translate(0, -50%);
                text-align: center;
                width: 40px;
                z-index: 10;
            }

            .carousel-control.prev {
            left: 2%;
            }

            .carousel-control.next {
            right: 2%;
            }

            .carousel-control:hover {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            color: #aaaaaa;
            }

            #carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
            #carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
            #carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 {
            display: block;
            }

            .carousel-indicators {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 2%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 10;
            background-color: transparent;
            }

            .carousel-indicators li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 5px;
            background-color: transparent;
            }

            .carousel-bullet {
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            font-size: 35px;
    
            background-color: transparent;
            }

            .carousel-bullet:hover {
            color: #aaaaaa;
            }

            #carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
            #carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
            #carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet {
            color: #428bca;
            }

            #title {
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px auto;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 27px;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            z-index: 9999;
            text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            }


            html, body {
                        margin: 0px;
                        padding: 0px;
                        background: url("http://digital.bnint.com/filelib/s9/photos/white_wood_4500x3000_lo_res.jpg");
                        background-color: black;
                }

            .carousel1 {
                        position: relative;
                        box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64);
                        margin-top: 26px;
                    }

            .carousel1-inner {
                        position: relative;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        width: 100%;
                    }

            .carousel1-open:checked + .carousel1-item {
                        position: static;
                        opacity: 100;
                    }

            .carousel1-item {
                position: absolute;
                opacity: 0;
                -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
                transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
    
                margin-left: 800px;
            }

            .carousel1-item img {
                display: block;
                height: auto;
                max-width: 100%;
            }

            .carousel1-control {
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
                border-radius: 50%;
                color: #fff;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: none;
                font-size: 40px;
                height: 40px;
                line-height: 35px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
                cursor: pointer;
                -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
                transform: translate(0, -50%);
                text-align: center;
                width: 40px;
                z-index: 10;
            }

            .carousel1-control.prev {
            left: 2%;
            }

            .carousel1-control.next {
            right: 2%;
            }

            .carousel1-control:hover {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            color: #aaaaaa;
            }

            #carousel1-1:checked ~ .control-1,
            #carousel1-2:checked ~ .control-2,
            #carousel1-3:checked ~ .control-3 {
            display: block;
            }

            .carousel1-indicators {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 2%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 10;
            background-color: transparent;
            }

            .carousel1-indicators li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 5px;
            background-color: transparent;
            }

            .carousel1-bullet {
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            font-size: 35px;
    
            background-color: transparent;
            }

            .carousel1-bullet:hover {
            color: #aaaaaa;
            }

            #carousel1-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel1-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel1-bullet,
            #carousel1-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel1-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel1-bullet,
            #carousel1-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel1-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel1-bullet {
            color: #428bca;
            }

            #title {
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px auto;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 27px;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            z-index: 9999;
            text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            }



            

            
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.19);
}
```

i have tried the code a few times and i see that at first when i click the arrow button to move to the next image, for a few millisecond the popup redirects me correctly, after that, the correct popup does not work and when i click on the image it comes up with the wrong popup.